# React - event.target is undefined/null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using React Hooks. And I want to update state to one function that uses event.target, event.name.

But event object in handling function returned undefined(Both event.target, event.name)
So states did not update.

Can you give me the reason? Please give some advice.
(I'm not used to English. If you feel uncomfortable I'm sorry)

Here is my code :
(in same js files, same function component)

Slider and Input import from material-ui

```
import Slider from "@material-ui/core/Slider";
import Input from "@material-ui/core/Input";
```

variables

```
const Mainpage = () => {
  const [squares, setSquares] = useState([
    {
      top: 20,
      left: 0,
      shadowX: 0,
      ...
    },
    ...
  ]);

  const [isSquareClick, setIsSquareClick] = useState(false);

  const [divNow, setDivNow] = useState(0);
```

Handling Function :

```
const handlingFocus = (index) => {
  setIsSquareClick(true);
  setDivNow(index);
};

const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value); // undefined
    console.log(e.target.name); //undefined
    console.log(squares[divNow].shadowX); // 0(deault value)
    console.log(divNow); // 0
    if (e.target.value !== "") {
      setSquares(
        squares.map((item) =>
          item.id === divNow
            ? { ...item, [e.target.name]: parseInt(e.target.value) }
            : item
        )
      );
    }
  };
```

JSX:

```
Shadow X : &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <Slider
            defaultValue={0}
            min={-100}
            max={100}
            style={{ width: "60%" }}
            value={
              typeof squares[divNow].shadowX === "number"
                ? String(squares[divNow].shadowX)
                : 0
            }
            aria-labelledby="input-slider" 
            onChange={(event) => {
              handleChange(event);
            }}
            name="shadowX"
          />
          <Input
            style={{ width: "10%", marginLeft: "5%" }}
            value={String(squares[divNow].shadowX)}
            margin="dense"
            onChange={(event) => {
              handleChange(event);
            }}
            inputProps={{
              step: 0.5,
              min: -100,
              max: 100,
              type: "number",
              "aria-labelledby": "input-slider",
            }}
            name="shadowX"
          />
```

I knew why!!
event.target didn't return input... :(...
sometimes it return div or span or input...

Comment: You have some non-default implementation of `input`, it's not an html element, so tell us what is it...

Comment: Your handler is `handleChange`, but that's never used in your JSX, which uses `handleChangeNum`. Is that meant to be the same function? Do `Slider` and `Input` fire the change event with a `value`? Please show the definitions of those.

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry `handleChangeNum` and `handleChange` is same function. and `Slider` and `Input` are from material-ui(provieded by google). It contains value and onChange props like HTML `input` element.

Comment: I am sympathized with you. Yet my account is locked from asking question -_-

Answer (score 0):

I am using alternative way, passing value directly to handler function.

For example, I am coding Pagination component

```
for (let idx = startIdx; idx < endIdx; idx++) {
  const offset = idx + 1;
  render.push(
    <Button
      key={`page-${offset}`}
      onClick={() => handlePageClick(idx)}
    >
      {offset}
    </Button>
  );
}

const handlePageClick = (value) => {
  console.log(`page request: ${value}, current page: ${currentPage}`);
  // Do sth here ._.
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you should also provide the details of the `<Slider>` component for a deeper understanding of this. However, one reason I can think of is that your handling function is named `handleChange`, but your components are calling a function named `handleChangeNum` in their onChange handlers.

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry `handleChangeNum` and `handleChange` is same function. and `Slider` and `Input` are from material-ui(provieded by google). It contains value and onChange props like HTML `input` element.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if this solves your problem, but wouldn't the idiomatic inline function look like `onChange={event => handleChange(event)}`? Alternately, I think the `event` is passed by default, without needing you to reference it in your source, so you can just do `onChange = {handleChange}`.

Comment: Thank you for advice. I changed and it also works. But still event.target returned undefined